# RallyComboBox clears filter after drop down

Tags: rally

I have a simple RallyComboBox created with the following code:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

items: [
    { xtype: 'container', itemId: 'toolbar', cls: 'toolbar' }
],

launch: function() {
    this.nameBox = this.down('#toolbar').add({
        xtype: 'rallycombobox',
        storeConfig: {
            model: 'User',
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [
                {
                    property: 'FirstName',
                    value: 'Conner'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
}
});
```

The box renders correctly and the filters are being applied at first. The problem is that after I click the arrow to expand the drop down the filter is cleared and all users are displayed on the drop down. I've searched through the documentation and I am still not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the following in the storeConfig to prevent external filtering:

```
remoteFilter: false
```

While you're at it, you may as well set the following, as well:

```
remoteGroup: false,
remoteSort: false
```